# Is it possible to store additional properties for a table in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a table with a unique name. The name is created in a format:

```
 name= tableName+ | +encryptedKey
```

and this throws the error

```
near "|": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table test2|<encryptedKey>
```

I also tried other characters like `@,-,#,$` to separate the name and encrypted key

Please note that the encrypted key may contain all those wierd characters as it is not human readable.

What are the valid delimiters can I use for a table name ?

If this is not possible, Can I store the encrypted key in the table without creating an additional column for it ?

Are there any hidden columns for a table in sqlite ?

Comment: No, identifiers in SQLite3 cannot contain arbitrary data. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to store the encrypted key in table name itself, so that it avoids to maintain another table just for the encryption key for the table created in sqlite-master table

Comment: Why do you need encryption keys for each table, and why are you storing the keys in the database itself right next to the encrypted data? An attacker will have no trouble extracting the keys if they have the database file.

Comment: I can't discuss furthermore about why I am doing that.  I wonder if there is a way to append metadata to table name. As sqlite-master is read only table, I am looking into put the data in table name itself.

Comment: It's not practical. You could potentially set [`PRAGMA writable_schema`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema) to on and add a column, but that's a really bad hack and, as the docs warn, a good way to corrupt your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table/column names containing special characters must be quoted (inside the name, quotes must be doubled):

```
CREATE TABLE "test2|any""thing..." (...);
```

But to assign data to your tables, just create your own metadata table:

```
CREATE TABLE AdditionalProperties(
    TableName TEXT,
    EncryptedKey TEXT
);
```

Comment: It says unrecognised token ""my_encrypted_key"" (code 1): while compiling

Comment: I am trying to put "test2$any"encypted_key"thing..."

Comment: when I removed the pipe character and try to do "test2any"my_key"thing...", i got code 1 near syntax error

Comment: ok....the problem is encypted key itslef is having double quotes in it too....and the double quotes I surround to it clashes to the quotes in it.

Comment: As I said, double quotes characters must be doubled. `"` → `""`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.